# Proving a function is a linear map

Tags: linear-algebra

2 questions regarding how to prove linear map, I know i need to use addition and scalar multiplication condition theorems but besides that I'm not sure what needs to be done to prove for questions of this format

[image]
[image]

Comment: Nothing else: only to prove the function respects addition of vectors and multiplication by scalars.

Comment: That images are not searcheable is only one reason, why text and formulae should always be written out rather than linked as images.

Comment: Consider formatting this post with MathJax. Tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the definition of the map and the properties of the operations of  addition and scalar multiplication in the two vector spaces.

E.g. for the second map, given $a(z)=a_0+a_1z+a_2z^2$, $b(z)=b_0+b_1z+b_2z^2$ and $u \in \mathbb{C}$ we have to prove that:
$$
T\left(ua(z) \right)=uT\left(a(z) \right) \qquad (1)
$$

Using the properties of scalar multiplication in $\mathbb{P}^2$ we have:

$$u(a(z))=u(a_0+a_1z+a_2z^2)=ua_0+ua_1z+ua_2z^2 $$
now, using the definition of $T$: 
$$
T\left(ua(z) \right)=T\left((ua_0)+(ua_1)z+(ua_2)z^2 \right)=
\begin{pmatrix}ua_0\\ua_1\\ua_2\end{pmatrix}
$$
that, using the properties of the scalar multiplication in $\mathbb{C}^3$ becomes:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}ua_0\\ua_1\\ua_2\end{pmatrix}=u\begin{pmatrix}a_0\\a_1\\a_2\end{pmatrix}
$$
that, by definition of $T$ is:
$$
u\begin{pmatrix}a_0\\a_1\\a_2\end{pmatrix}=uT(a(z))
$$
so we have proved (1).

We can do the same for:
$$
T(a(z)+b(z))=T(a(z))+T(b(z))\qquad (2)
$$
 we have:
$$
a(z)+b(z)= (a_0+b_0)+(a_1+b_1)z+(a_2+b_2)z
$$

and 
$$T(a(z)+b(z))=
T((a_0+b_0)+(a_1+b_1)z+(a_2+b_2)z)=\begin{pmatrix}
a_0+b_0\\a_1+b_1\\a_2+b_2
\end{pmatrix}= \begin{pmatrix}
a_0\\a_1\\a_2
\end{pmatrix}+\begin{pmatrix}
b_0\\b_1\\b_2
\end{pmatrix}
$$
$$=T(a(z))+T(b(z))$$

Can you do the same for the first function?

Comment: Yes, i can. Thank you for the help.